# Error when running an exe file within a program

Tags: matlab, exe

I have compiled an exe file with a MATLAB script. The exe seem to run fine on its own. It produces the wanted output without any error message. But **when I run the exe-file within another program** the exe file produces the following error:

> Too many input arguments Error in mclFreeStackTrace

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Probably an issue of a different working directory.

Comment: The exe file runs fine on its own the very same directory as when I run it in another programme, so how can it be related to working directory?

Comment: If you star a file with some code like `cd c:\bla`  `c:\blub\test.exe` the test.exe might miss files which are placed in the same directory, because the working directory is set to `c:\bla`

Comment: Hmm but the as the documentation says "model simulation in program A can be defined as a sequence of individual
model runs". So the exe program run independently in a sequence with another program.

Comment: The rest of the documentation is as follows, maybe you could point at something I have missed. "Program A will execute program B based numerical calculation kernels as well as any executable (.exe) or batch (.bat) file. In this case the model simulation file for the numerical engine (e.g. a .type 1 file for a program 1) or the name of the .exe or .bat file must be specified in the Model simulation sequence column. If the executable file requires arguments, such as an input file name or some simulation options, these are written in the Optional arguments column."